# Cannot declare unconventional PK via Data Annotations for a MVC3 Entity Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, data-annotations, entity-framework-4.1

I'm trying to declare a Primary Key for an **Entity Model** that will eventually be consumed by **ASP.NET MVC3** to create a Controller class, for that reason I'm decorating a value with the `[Key]` attribute:

**Foobar.cs**

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

public class Foobar
{
  [Key]
  public string Foo { get; set; }
  public string Bar { get; set; }
}
```

**FoobarDbContext.cs**

```
using System.Data.Entity;

public class FoobarDBContext : DbContext
{
  public DbSet<Foobar> Foobars { get; set; }
}
```

Which when attempting to create the aforementioned **Controller** results in the following error:

```
---------------------------
Microsoft Visual Studio
---------------------------
Unable to retrieve metadata for 'Dotnet.Samples.AspNetMvc.Models.FoobarDBContext'.
One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:

- System.Data.Edm.EdmEntityType: : EntityType 'Foobar' has no key defined.
Define the key for this EntityType.

- System.Data.Edm.EdmEntityType: : EntityType 'FoobarDBContext' has no key defined.
Define the key for this EntityType.

- System.Data.Edm.EdmEntitySet: EntityType: EntitySet __Foobars__
is based on type ?Foo? that has no keys defined.

- System.Data.Edm.EdmEntitySet: EntityType: EntitySet __FoobarDBContexts__
is based on type __FoobarDBContext__ that has no keys defined.


---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

Any suggestion will be really appreciated. Thanks much in advance,

**UPDATE**

According to [Data Annotations in the Entity Framework and Code First](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2010/03/30/data-annotations-in-the-entity-framework-and-code-first.aspx)

> KeyAttribute is used to specify that a
>   property/column is part of the primary
>   key of the entity and *applies to
>   scalar properties only*.

Therefore I guess I'd have to go ahead and create a 'non-semantic' identifier such as `FoobarID` in order to take advantage of the code generation functionality.

Comment: This shouldn't be necessary, I have a class `User` with the primary key defined as follows: `[Key]public string UserName { get; set; }`, and it works perfectly... Is there any other info about the class `FooBar` that might be relevant?

Comment: @Sergi: Thanks for your comment. I don't think there is much more relevant info about `Foobar`, I'd go ahead and create a new MVC3 project from scratch and eventually I'd post the source to a free repo / dropbox public folder.

Comment: @Nano - One other thing, a scalar property is ***"A property of an entity that maps to a single field in a storage schema"***, so it should not be a problem to try and use a string property as the PK. Not a very helpful remark, I know, but it sort of indicates that there's something else going on.

Comment: @Sergi: thanks a lot for the contribution, I've actually started a test project from scratch, decorated a string as a PK and it worked. I have no idea why I've had that error on the first attempt. Would you mind posting your comments as an answer so I can mark it as answered and give you the credit?

Comment: @Nano - Using the same database? Well, glad you can move forward anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This shouldn't be necessary, I have a class User with the primary key defined as follows:

```
[Key]
public string UserName { get; set; }
```

and it works perfectly... Is there any other info about the class FooBar that might be relevant?

One other thing, a scalar property is ["A property of an entity that maps to a single field in a storage schema"](http://www.google.com/search?sclient=psy&hl=en&source=hp&q=define%3A+scalar+property&aq=&aqi=&aql=&oq=&pbx=1), so it should not be a problem to try and use a string property as the PK. Not a very helpful remark, I know, but it sort of indicates that there's something else going on.

Comment: Just a detail: for some reason the property marked as `[Key]` is not getting exposed e.g. when you access the `Controller` at `http://localhost:XXXX/Foobars` you can't give `Foo` a value.

Comment: And does the `Foobar` table have a `Foo` PK in the database?

Comment: I haven't checked really what has been written to the persistence as I'm using the Code-First approach but I'll do that -- thanks!